# Permutation question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Leading zeros are not allowed

1) How many seven-digit numbers have no repeated digits? Would this one be $9*P(9,6)$

2) How many seven-digit numbers with no repeated digits contain a 3 but not a 6? And would this be  $8*P(9,6)$

Comment: What have your tried?

Answer (score 1):

For 1, you are correct.  The first digit has 9 choices, then the rest have $P(9,6)$ to deal with the no duplicates requirement

For 2, you have done nothing to require a 3, nor to prohibit a 6 except in the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for the first problem:

How many ways can you fill the millions place?  (The answer is $9$.  Why?)  Then, how many ways can you fill the hundred thousands place (without repeating anything)?  (Again, it's $9$.  Why?)  What about the ten thousands place?  (This time it's $8$.)  And so forth.  Multiply them together.

For the second problem:

Since you can't have leading zeroes, try two cases.  You know you need a $3$ in there, so make that the millions place.  Then how many ways can you build up that number without repeating digits?  Now, make the first digit something other than $3$ (but not $0$ or $6$, of course).  You'll still need a $3$ later in the number.  How many ways can you build up this one?  Add these two totals together.

Answer (score 0):

question 1:

$9*9*8*7*6*5*4$

question 2:
case 1: number 3 is in first digit: then $8*7*6*5*4*3$

case 2: number 3 is not in first digit: then

$6*7*7*6*5*4*3$

Comment: For 2, second batch, why do we know a $3$ is one of the digits?  How can the third factor be $8$-there are two digits that cannot be matched and $6$ is not allowed?

Comment: thanks, does this look good to you? the 6 is to position the 3. the remaining ones create a number not containing a 3 or 6 or starting with 0.

Comment: Going back to start with 3, it should just be 8*7*6*5*4 as there are only five more digits to pick.  Then for the second batch, you already counted the ones starting with 3, so you only have 5 choices for the 3 position.  Then you are fighting the leading zero.  I would say 7(leading digit not 0,3,6)*5(places for the 3)*7*6*5*4(choices for each digit besides the first and the 3)

Comment: but they are 7 digit numbers. shouldn't there be 6 left to pick?

Answer (score 0):

1) There are $9$ choices for the first digit. For every choice of first digit, there are $9$ allowed choices for the second digit, since $0$ is now allowed, the only thing forbidden is the number we used for the first digit.

For every choice of first two digits, there are $8$ allowed choices for the third digit. And so on.

2) Here things are a little different if the first digit is a $3$, or not a $3$.

If the first digit is a $3$, that leaves $8$ allowed digits out of which to make the six-digit tail end (recall $6$ is not allowed). There are $(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)$ such tail ends.

If the first digit is not a $3$, there are $7$ allowed choices.  Now we need to place a $3$ somewhere. **Where** can be chosen in $6$ ways. That leaves $5$ empty slots, which can be filled from allowed digits in $(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)$ ways.

Now we put the pieces together.

**Another way:** For 2), we can easily imitate the process of 1) to get the number of strings that miss $6$. Call this number $x$.

Now count the strings that miss both $6$ and $3$. Call this number $y$.

The answer to 2) is then $x-y$.